# How can I accept all SSH requests?

Tags: ssh, rsa

I would like to have a VM accept all SSH requests. That is, anyone on the network (namely, the host) can SSH into the shell without password checking, public key, etc. I know this is largely against the premise of SSH, but is it possible?

Criterion: It should not be a VM hack; I want this to simulate two computers on the same network, one with 'swiss-cheese' security.

In summary: `ssh user_name@host_machine` should work, regardless of the nature of the ssh'ing machine, settings, RSA keys, etc.

Comment: You could recompile sshd to always accept the connection and log them in as some user...

Comment: Please remember to mention your OS. Both the host and the guest in this case. Answers are very likely to be OS-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- Recompile SSH to always accept no matter what the password (probably no more than a line or two needs to change)
- Modify your PAM stack to always accept for authentication. You can make this for *all* services, or you can specify an alternate PAM stack just for inbound SSH.

Note that I'm a bit rusty on PAM rules, and these are (*obviously*) not tested. So you may have to tweak things a bit to make it work. Feel free to edit if you get it working.

But for example to allow if the attempted username is listed in a file:

```
# in /etc/pam.d/sshd
auth sufficient pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=/etc/sshd_allowed_users onerr=fail
```

Or just permit everything:

```
# in /etc/pam.d/sshd
auth sufficient pam_permit.so
```

Presumably a user would have to pick the username of a valid account. But I'm not 100% certain as to what will happen.

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly what I was looking for (moreso the second solution, though I think the first one will come in handy as well). Tons of thanks! (Wish I had enough rep to upvote...)